# Override operator to handle none type

Tags: python, python-3.x, operator-overloading

How do i override `__iadd__` so that it handles `None`?

example:

```
var = None
myObject = MyObject()
var += myObject
var == myObject
>> True
```

If I just override `__iadd__` in `myObject` to handle adding two `MyObject`'s together i get this error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "", line 1, in
>    TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'NoneType' and
>   'myObject'

Comment: The equivalence between `var += myObject` and `var = var + myObject` that `+=` suggests isn't absolute. `+=` cannot make `var` refer to a new object. Despite its appearance, `+=` is *not* an assignment operator.

Comment: @chepner what?  Can you elaborate, in every language i've ever used immutables are handled as (var += myObject) == (var = var + myObject).

Comment: I worded that poorly (and overlooked the actual assignment); `x += y` is equivalent to `x = x + y` *if* `__iadd__` isn't defined; otherwise, it's equivalent to `x = x.__iadd__(y)`. The real problem is that `None` simply doesn't have an `__iadd__` method, and you can't add one.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is if var=None, then the `__iadd__` method is getting called on None, not on MyObject

```
class myobject:
    def __iadd__(self, other):
        if other is None:
            return self
        else:
            pass # Do stuff here
```

This works fine:

```
var = myobject()
var += None
```

But this wont:

```
var = None
var += myobject()
```

The best way to handle it is to just catch the error:

```
try:
    var += myobject()
except TypeError:
    var = myobject()
```